# onLocationChanged() is called too many times, even when the device hasn't move

Tags: android, coding-style, google-maps-android-api-2

I have implemented OnLocationChanged(Location location) as a overrided method in my Activity as shown:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

    mCurrentLocation = location;
    if (wifiSpotList != null) {
        presenter.onLocationUpdated(wifiSpotList, mCurrentLocation);
        centerInLoc(location);
    }
}
```

The problem is, this method get triggered even if the device is not moving. It always happens in an interval of milliseconds.

Debugger over location param gets me this logs:

```
mTime = 1446035851646
mLongitude = -3.6923793
mLatitude = 40.5008861

mTime = 1446035856976
mLongitude = -3.6923596
mLatitude = 40.5008932

mTime = 1446035867327
mLongitude = -3.6923681
mLatitude = 40.5008987

mTime = 1446035877344
mLongitude = -3.6923778
mLatitude = 40.5008949

mTime = 1446035882442
mLongitude = -3.6923734
mLatitude = 40.5008926

...
```

EDIT:

This is the code where requestLocationUpdates is initialized:

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    this.locationUpdatesStarted = true;
}
```

EDIT
mLocationRequest:

```
protected void createLocationRequest() {
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(LOCATION_REQUEST_FASTEST_INTERVAL);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
    this.mLocationRequest = mLocationRequest;
}
```

Is the method triggered because of longitud\latitud change? 
Why is it triggering even when the device is not moving? 
Can I limit the accuracy? 
Is there any clean way to implement onLocationChanged()?

Comment: show me the code where you called`requestLocationUpdates()` I think you have setted time-interval. second parameter in `requestLocationUpdates()` method.

Comment: I have added it to the question.

Comment: have you added `setInterval()` to your `mLocationRequest` variable?

Comment: I have added it too.

Comment: check `LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL` will be assigned to a integer value it is millisecond. for every interval time period of `LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL` it will update the location refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates.html)

Comment: Understood, `LOCATION_REQUEST_INTERVAL`  is set to 1 second (1000 ms) so it will ask for the location every second, but, why is called 'onLocationChanged' called? I read, android asks for location every second,  and if the location has changed, trigger the method, but only when the location has changed. Have I misunderstood ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setSmallestDisplacement(float smallestDisplacementMeters)
```

You have to set the minimum displacement between location updates in meters
By default it is 0.

Comment: I am having the same problem. smallestDisplacementMeter is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by setting

`mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);`

instead of

`mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);`

Then I set

`mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);` UPDATE_INTERVAL to 10 * 1000 milli seconds.

Also

`mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(200) // 200 meters`